# Timed loop, 10 second between

Tags: javascript

I currently got this:

```
var xnumLow = 3000;
var xnumHigh = 4900;

var ynumLow = 9969;
var ynumHigh = 13900;

var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

for (y=ynumLow; y<ynumLow; y++)
{
    for(x=xnumLow; x<xnumHigh; x++)
    {
        $('#box').append(y + " - " + x);
    }
}
```

Now I would like it to append new whole y "row" every 10 seconds, so they all dont append all in once.

The y "row" is the outer `for()` loop

How can I do this?

I got:

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function(){ (...) }, 10000);
```

But I don't know where to merge this with the above code, in order to work correct.

Comment: setInterval is BAD if you want precise delay as if your calculations take up 1 second, the next time function will be called is after 9seconds, not 10. Use setTimeout and reinitiate it in the end of a process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(function () {
    var xnumLow = 3000,
        xnumHigh = 4900,
        ynumLow = 9969,
        ynumHigh = 13900,
        currentY = ynumLow,
        delay = 500,
        displayData = function () {        
            var out = [],
            x;            
            for (x=xnumLow; x<xnumHigh; x++) {
                out.push( currentY + "-" + x );          
            }            
            console.log(out.join(","));  //do the append here      
            currentY++;            
            if (currentY<ynumHigh) {
                window.setTimeout(displayData,delay);
            }        
        };
    displayData()
})();
```

Comment: Great answer! But how would I do if i need delay 500ms for each x's for loop and 10000 ms for each y row ?

Comment: Than you need to break up the logic for the inside.

Comment: I'ma also a fan of this answer for it's function wrapper and good variable management. It does suffer from an off-by-one error, though. Since `currentY` gets incremented before it's checked, there will be one fewer row than the OP is looking to have. Change to `currentY <= ynumHigh` or put the `currentY++` inside the `if` block and it'll be perfect (also fix the delay).

Comment: @Pete, how is it off by one? The original code above is not a `<=`

Comment: @epascarello Oh my, you're right. We're doing a post-check loop. My bad!

Answer (score 1):

```
setInterval(function () {
    // code that appends a box
}, 10000);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setInterval

Comment: If i got the for loop inside this it will run the WHOLE 2 for loops each 10 seconds..

Comment: Whatever you put inside the callback will be executed in its entirety every 10 seconds. You'll probably have to change your logic to account for that.

Answer (score 1):

```
var y = ynumLow;

function addRow()
{
    for (x = xnumLow; x < xnumHigh; x++) {
        $('#box').append(y + " - " + x);
    }

    if (y++ < ynumHigh)
        refreshId = setTimeout(addRow, 10000);
}

addRow();
```

edited as Pete suggested for clarity

Comment: This is a good solution. The one concern I have is that it relies on the hoisted nature of the `addRow` function declaration. It's probably better to do this as an immediately invoked function expression or put the `addRow()` call *after* the function declaration for clarity's sake. It appears to work fine, though.

Answer (score 0):

I would do it something like this:

```
var xnumLow = 3000;
var xnumHigh = 4900;

var ynumLow = 9969;
var ynumHigh = 13900;
var x, y = ynumLow; //don't forget to declare your variables!

var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

(function addYRow() { //Create a function that adds the X elements
    for(x=xnumLow; x<xnumHigh; x++)
    {
        $('#box').append(y + " - " + x);
    }

    y++; //don't forget to increment y
    if(y < ynumHigh) { //only re-call if we aren't done yet
        setTimeout(addYRow, 10000); //Recall the function every 10 seconds.
    }
}());
```

Looking at some of the other answers, it's important to realize that you don't want to set up a bunch of things to happen 10 seconds from a given point (which is what happens if you do a loop calling `setTimeout()`. Instead, I assume you want to add a row, then wait 10 seconds, then add another row. This can only be achieved by adding a row (usiny, in my case, the `addYRow()` function), then delaying 10 seconds before re-calling the add-a-row function.

**Column Delay:**

In response to the question about how to do a 500ms delay in the x row, that's a little tricky, but not too bad. You just have to nest things one more time:

```
var y = ynumLow; //don't forget to declare your variables!

var ts = Math.round((new Date()).getTime() / 1000);

(function addYRow() { //Create a function that adds the X elements
    var x = xnumLow;
    (function addXCol() { //Create a function that adds each X element
        $('#box').append(y + " - " + x);

        x++;
        if(x < xnumHigh) { //if x is not done, call  addXCol 500ms later
            setTimeout(addXCol, 500);
        } else {
            y++;
            if(y < ynumHigh) { //If x is done but y isn't, call addYRow 10 seconds later
                setTimeout(addYRow, 10000); //Recall the function every 10 seconds.
            }
        }
    }());
}());
```

Note that if you want to delay the start of the column/row addition (e.g., if you want to put a 500ms delay between when a row is added and when the first column is added, you'll need to adjust the `addXCol()` expression creation to look like this:

```
setTimeout(function addXCol() { //Create a function that adds each X element
    //...
}, 500);
```

This will put that initial delay in. Hope that helps.

Comment: But how would I do if i need delay 500ms for each x's for loop and 10000 ms for each y row ? I'll give you +100 bounty for a solution with this too

Comment: @Karem Here ya go. Wasn't a big deal to add that functionality.

Answer (score -1):

Something like this?

```
var refreshId = setInterval(function(){
  $('#box').append(++y + " - " + x);
}, 10000);
```

Comment: ++y ?? and where does y come from? i would need it inside for loop then ?

Comment: Add `if (y > ynumHigh) { clearInterval(refreshId); return; }`