# Timed loops, x seconds between 2 loops with Javascript

Tags: javascript

Continue from this:
[Timed loop, 10 second between](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12319813/timed-loop-10-second-between)

Which gave me a great answer on how I could make the loop on the outer for() each 10 seconds. (the Y)

Now I wish to make the inner loop, the X, so loop once each 1 second, and keep the outer loop (the 'Y') at 10000ms (10 seconds)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add `currentX` in a similar way to `currentY`. Then, instead of incrementing `currentY` you should increment `currentX`. If `currentX` is not less than `xnumHigh` then set it back to `xnumLow` and increment `currentY`.

Basically you're just doing the exact same thing as you did to put `y` on a timer, just with `x` instead.

Comment: Here's what I understood and did out from your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/hnFse/ ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it: (the canvas stuff is merely a visual representation)

http://jsfiddle.net/J5GvM/1/

```
(function nestedLoop(){
    var innerStep = 10;
    var xnumLow = 0;
    var xnumHigh = 500;
    var currentX = xnumLow;

    var outerStep = 3000;
    var ynumLow = 0;
    var ynumHigh = 500;
    var currentY = ynumLow;

    var canvas = $("#canvas")[0];
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    var drawPixel = function(x, y){
        ctx.fillRect(x,y,1,1);
    };

    (function outerLoop(oStart, oEnd){
        currentX = xnumLow;
        currentY = oStart;

        (function innerLoop(iStart, iEnd){
            currentX = iStart;

            // Do stuff here
            drawPixel(currentX, currentY);

            if (iStart < iEnd)
                setTimeout(function(){innerLoop(++iStart, iEnd);}, innerStep); 
            else
                setTimeout(function(){outerLoop(++oStart, oEnd);}, outerStep);
        })(currentX, xnumHigh);
    })(currentY, ynumHigh);
})();​
```